# How to remove Indent while using book document class

Tags: titles, indentation, document-classes

while working on a project I noticed that some pages have a slight indent over the pages above them. you'll notice that all text on page 12, for example, is slightly more indented than page 11.

I also have another issue with the title(above the horizontal line) at the very top of every page being sometimes the title of the section but I want the title to always be the title of the chapter

How do I fix these 2 issues?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[ER]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OR]{\thepage}


%opening
\title{MWE}
\author{A1}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{intro 1}
\lipsum

\section {intro 2}
\lipsum 

\makeatletter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Something1}
\lipsum 

\subsection{Motivation}
\lipsum 

%SURVEY DETAILS
\subsection{Something 2}
\lipsum 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please ask two separate questions.

Comment: The `book` class assumes a two sided document by default, which means that left and right pages have different left and right margins. Use the option `[oneside]` if you don't want that. For your second question see [\`fancyhdr\` to include just Chapter in header](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/252386).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible answer to your first question (the one in the title): 
Does `\documentclass[oneside]{book}` solve your problem (option `oneside` is important)?

---

- Based on your previous questions, I recommend to read a proper LaTeX
  introduction rather then solving one problem after another by asking
  micro questions.
- Consider to have a look at:
  [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/).
- I recommend to read a
  book first and online later.
- In addition, make sure that you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Before the edit you suggested, hypothetically speaking, anything that wasn't indented was, for example, 3 cm from the leftmost start of the page and everything that was indented was at 5 cm.
After you edit, everything is now is indented the same but they all start 4cm from the left most of the page. but I want it to be the 3 cm that I had before the edit.
How can I do that?

Comment: @Zyzzx If my answer solves the problem of your question, the please consider accepting it (this is how this website works). Your comment is, again, another question. You want to change the page layout. Have a look at the `geometry` package. This website here expects one question per post and not multiple questions or follow up questions within the same question. Please make sure, that you know what you want and ask another precise question (or first read a LaTeX introduction as mentioned in my answer).

Comment: @Zyzzx On margins see [Setting exact margins](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/46175). But do spend some time reading some introductory material.